# Jekyll website npot displaying images on github

Tags: jekyll

I have a simple Jekyll web site. It displays images in web pages on the local server, but they do not appear when the site is loaded on github

E.g. in the page *post01.md* I have the code

```
![](/wx_python/images/raw_frame.png)
```

This is my tree

```
.
├── 404.html
├── about.markdown
├── _config.yml
├── Gemfile
├── Gemfile.lock
├── index.md
├── _posts
├── _site
│   ├── 404.html
│   ├── about
│   │   └── index.html
│   ├── assets
│   │   ├── main.css
│   │   ├── main.css.map
│   │   └── minima-social-icons.svg
│   ├── feed.xml
│   ├── index.html
│   └── wx_python
│       ├── images
│       │   ├── raw_frame.png
│       ├── introduction.html
│       ├── post01.html
│       ├── post02.html
│       ├── post03.html
│       ├── post04.html
│       ├── snippets
│       │   ├── basic_frame.py
│       │   ├── basic_panel.py
│       └── wxpython_from_scratch.html
└── wx_python
    ├── images
    │   ├── raw_frame.png
    ├── introduction.md
    ├── post01.md
    ├── post02.md
    ├── snippets
    │   ├── basic_frame.py
    │   ├── basic_panel.py
    └── wxpython_from_scratch.md
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that I was not giving Jeckyll the *baseurl*. The code to display the image should be

```
![]({{ site.baseurl }}/wx_python/images/raw_frame.png)
```

see the [answer here](https://talk.jekyllrb.com/t/why-are-there-differences-between-jekyll-on-local-server-and-github/4127/7) (this seems to be a more responsive forum for Jekyll that SO)